# How do I stop an INTERRUPT_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED on my mv91xx.sys driver?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bsod, sata, interrupts

I have an EVGA motherboard with a `Marvell MV99SE91` SATA 6 driver. When I go to their [driver downloads page](http://www.evga.com/support/download/), navigate to `Intel X58/ICH10R` / `141-GT-E770 - EVGA X58 Classified3` / `All` / `Windows 7 64-bit`, and install the Sata 6 driver, it causes blue screens.

I installed it because, obviously, I want SATA 6 over SATA 3 for my two SSDs. Sadly, I've gotten 2-3 blue screens of death with the message INTERRUPT_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED. Is it possible to fix this or do I just need to uninstall my driver?

Comment: Are you using a SATA III capable SSD? If not just uninstall it. (All current HDD's are way slower than the max speed of SATA II, so you do not gain any real life speed by using SATA III for most devices).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using SSDs. The Windows Experience Index went from 5.9 to 7.9 after I installed the driver.

Comment: Why did I get a -1 for this? I posted a very detailed question and searched for this prior to posting. I found nothing.

Comment: Not my -1. I usually leave a comment with the reason in it when I downvote. You might want to add that what you tried though, because one of the down vote reasons often is 'did not show any research prior to posting.' As work toward solutions: Are dump files enabled? If you analyse them they usually tell you in which part the error occured (which can be the marvel drivers, but it can be something else).

Comment: I think downvoting without commenting is either ignorant or cowardly. I undeleted this question because I found an answer and anyone else with this issue deserves to have it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this thread](http://forums.evga.com/tm.aspx?m=2031822), the Marvell driver provided by EVGA was outdated and needed to be installed from Marvell's website:

http://www.marvell.com/support/downloads/search.do

I chose the `Windows Setup Installer (32- and 64-bit) for Yukon Controllers`. There's also a `Windows 8 Installer`.